# How to access elements in a list in c++

Tags: c++

I am working through problems in Accelerated C++
We have a program which stores strings in vectors and outputs them according to certain rules.
The original code fragment is as follows.

```
typedef vector<string> Rule;
typedef vector<Rule> Rule_collection;
typedef map<string, Rule_collection> Grammar;


// read a grammar from a given input stream
Grammar read_grammar(istream& in)
{
    Grammar ret;
    string line;

    // read the input
    while (getline(in, line)) {

        // `split' the input into words
        vector<string> entry = split(line);

        if (!entry.empty())
            // use the category to store the associated rule
            ret[entry[0]].push_back(
                Rule(entry.begin() + 1, entry.end()));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

We are then asked to use lists instead of vectors.

So all the vectors above will now become lists.

The bit I am stuck on is how to deal with the line beginning ret[entry]].push_back etc. Also what to put in after Rule...
I have tried using entry.begin() but that doesn't work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which `vector` do you want to replace with a `list`? All of them?

Comment: Yes, that's right larsmans. I think the author wants us to learn the difference between how vectors and lists work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to replace your code with something like this:

```
ret[*(entry.begin())].push_back(
            Rule(++(entry.begin()), entry.end()));
```

Comment: That works. Thank you very much.The code then selects a random rule. Because the vectors have now changed to lists, this part of the code does not now work:                                                               // fetch the set of possible rules
  const Rule_collection& c = it->second;

  //// from which we select one at random
  const Rule& r = c[nrand(c.size())];

Comment: Try `list<string>::iterator it = c.begin(); std::advance(it, nrand(c.size()); Rule &r = *it;`

Comment: Just a side notice - are you sure you have to use list instead of vector? List is not the right container if you need random access. Maybe `deque` is a better choice.

Comment: Hi a1ex07. Yes, the reader is supposed to use a list even though we know it is not suitable for these cases. It's all practice.

Answer (score 2):

with list you can perform most of the operations you can with vector but you cannot use `entry[0]` as there is no random-access.

`entry.front()` will get that element instead.

Also you cannot add 1 to `entry.begin()` because it is bi-directional and does not support +, but you can assign it to a temporary iterator then `++it`.

Answer (score 1):

```
entry.begin ()
```

returns an iterator to the start of the list, whereas

```
entry [0]
```

for vector returns the first element, so I think you want something like the following

```
*(entry.begin ())
```

EDIT:

Hopefully I understood what you are asking... Other than that begin and end should return comparable values for both vector and list

Comment: I would like to thank everyone who answered. You have been most helpful. Could I just ask: do you think C++ is among the most difficult of computer languages?

Answer (score 0):

`begin()` gives you an iterator to the beginning of the list.  You could dereference the iterator, which gives you the first value...

```
ret[*(entry.begin())].push_back(...
```

Or you could use the `front()` function, which returns the element at the front of a list (technically a reference, but should work in this case).

```
ret[entry.front()].push_back(...
```

EDIT:

As others have pointed out, this works provided `entry` is a `std::list<string>`, as you implied.

Comment: Thanks for that. This seems to work for the first part (Visual Studio is not highlighting any of it in red). 
Any ideas on the part beginning with Rule?

Answer (score 0):

`ret[entry[0]]` calls `Grammar::operator[]` passing it a `string`: the string contained in `entry[0]`, which is the first string put in such vector by `split`.

Supposing that `split` returns a `std::list`, you should just take the first element of the list:

```
ret[ entry.front() ] ... // where entry is a std::list<string>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is pretty generic- it should just work when you change the typedefs, except a couple of minor niggles like `std::list` does not give random-access iterators, and since you don't show the code I can't speak about `split`.